# Rails: OUTER JOIN with condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models Show and Booking. A show has many bookings. Each booking has a start_date and end_date. I want to find the shows that either i) have no bookings or ii) have bookings that do not overlap with a time interval [start, end]. So far I have:

```
Show.joins("LEFT JOIN bookings ON bookings.show_id = shows.id").where("bookings.start_date > ? OR bookings.end_date < ?, end, start)
```

But it doesn't return the shows that have no bookings. How can I include the shows that have no bookings in the query result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Show.joins("LEFT JOIN bookings ON bookings.show_id = shows.id").where("bookings.id IS NULL OR bookings.start_date > ? OR bookings.end_date < ?", end, start)
```

Comment: That works! One more question, if I have more than one bookings for a show that do not overlap with the query interval, LEFT JOIN will return duplicated rows. Is there any way to get rid of the duplication?

Comment: Got it. I can use "GROUP BY boats.id"